# Positive semidefinite matrix ordering and nuclear norm of products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, nuclear-norm

Let $A, A', B, B'$ be finite-dimensional, complex-valued, Hermitian, positive-semidefinite matrices. Moreover, let $(A-A')$ and $(B-B')$ also be positive-semidefinite.

The 1-norm is defined as $\|X\|_1 = Tr(\sqrt{X^*X})$ where $X^*$ is the transpose conjugate of $X$. Can one claim anything about the relationship between $\|AB\|_1$ and $\|A'B'\|_1$? In particular is

$$\|AB\|_1\geq \|A'B'\|_1?$$

If not, can someone show a counterexample?

Comment: It would be equivalent to show that $\|AB\|_1 \geq \|AB'\|_1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample: take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&1}, \quad A' = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad v = \pmatrix{3 - \sqrt{13}\\2}, \quad B = B' = vv^*.
$$
We find that
$$
\|AB\|_1 \approx 3.35 < \|A'B\|_1 \approx 4.12.
$$

---

Let $A \succeq A'$ denote the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), which is to say that $A \succeq A'$ iff $A - A'$ is positive semidefinite.

To ensure that $\|AB\|_1 \geq \|A'B'\|_1$,
it would suffice to have $A^2 \succeq [A']^2$ and $B^2 \succeq [B']^2$. Note that [this does not follow](https://www-m5.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M5/Allgemeines/OS_MAQT_2018W/h5.pdf) from the fact that $A\succeq A'$ and $B\succeq B'$ are positive semidefinite. However, because the square root is operator monotone, we have $A^2 \succeq [A']^2 \implies A \succeq A'$.

We can prove the weakened result as follows. First, we see that $\|AB\|_1 \geq \|A'B\|_1$. Note that
$$
(AB)^*(AB) - (A'B)^*(A'B) = \\
BA^2B - B(A')^2B = \\
B(A^2 - [A']^2)B \succeq 0.
$$
Because $(AB)^*(AB) \succeq (A'B)^*(A'B)$, the operator monotonicity of the square root ensures that $\sqrt{(AB)^*(AB)} \succeq \sqrt{(A'B)^*(A'B)}$, from which it follows that
$$
\|AB\|_1 = \operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{(AB)^*(AB)}) \geq 
\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{(A'B)^*(A'B)}) = \|A'B\|_1.
$$
With that, we may conclude that
$$
\|AB\|_1 \geq \|A'B\|_1 = \|(A'B)^*\|_1 = \|BA'\|_1 \geq \|B'A'\|_1 = \|(B'A')^*\|_1 = \|A'B'\|_1.
$$